# How to get data from Json type

Tags: json, flutter

I have tried for a long time to get data from Json Local file.

At this moment my code is like:

```
static Future<String> loadJsonData() async {
    var jsonText = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/Json/CDV.json');
    data = json.decode(jsonText);
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      print(data[i]);
    }
    
    return 'success';
  }
```

And I got:

> {attributes: {FID: 2618, id: 2619, Adresse:  Banque Atlantique -
> Agence Vridi, Zone Industrielle Abidjan-Ville  Lagunes Côte d'Ivoire,
> longitude: -4.000757, latitude: 5.265247}, geometry: {x: -4.000757, y:
> 5.265247}} I/flutter (26638): {attributes: {FID: 2619, id: 2620, Adresse:  Prestige Auto Abidjan-Ville  Lagunes Côte d'Ivoire,
> longitude: -4.002028, latitude: 5.266179}, geometry: {x: -4.002028, y:
> 5.266179}} I/flutter (26638): {attributes: {FID: 2620, id: 2621, Adresse: banque Société générale Côte d’Ivoire Agence Vridi
> Abidjan-Ville  Lagunes Côte d'Ivoire, longitude: -4.004049, latitude:
> 5.268738}, geometry: {x: -4.004049, y: 5.268738}} I/flutter (26638): {attributes: {FID: 2621, id: 2622, Adresse: banque Bicici - Agence
> Vridi Abidjan-Ville  Lagunes Côte d'Ivoire, longitude: -4.013067,
> latitude: 5.266223}, geometry: {x: -4.013067, y: 5.266223}} I/flutter
> (26638): {attributes: {FID: 2622, id: 2623, Adresse:  Bank of Africa
> (BOA) - Agence Vridi Abidjan-Ville  Lagunes Côte d'Ivoire, longitude:
> -4.008449, latitude: 5.266771}, geometry: {x: -4.008449, y: 5.266771}}

I want to extract from that adress List from that response but I can't reach to it;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the `attributes` then `address` like this
`data[i]['attributes']['Adresse']`

```
static Future<String> loadJsonData() async {
    var jsonText = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/Json/CDV.json');
    data = json.decode(jsonText);
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      print(data[i]['attributes']['Adresse']);
    }
    
    return 'success';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
class Address {
  final int FID;
  final String addr;

  Address(this.addr, this.FID);

  Address.fromMap(Map m)
      : this.addr = m["Adresse"],
        this.FID = m["FID"];
}

static Future<List<Address>> loadJsonData() async {
    var jsonText = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/Json/CDV.json');
    data = json.decode(jsonText);
    var list = [];
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      list.add(Address.fromMap(data[i]["attributes"]);
    }
    
    return list;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50952582/7617512) using the same way
or you can use flutter package [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) from [google](https://pub.dev/publishers/google.dev/packages) easily using to get json data and serialize it